# Defining values based on other values comes up with no Data

Tags: python, dependencies, populate

I have this bit of code.

```
  class GRIDCODE:
    pass
def change(BSMPW):
if GRIDCODE == "1":
  return "BSM"
elif GRIDCODE == "3":
  return "BSE"
elif GRIDCODE == "4":
  return "BSP"
else:
  return "None"
```

What I want it to do is if the value in column a is 1, populate column b the value BSM and so forth. If there is no data, write None.
The result is that it writes into every single row "None" which is wrong because the column I am looking at (GRIDCODE) is populated with the values 1,3 and 4.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 6/25/14 4:31 PM

I'll try to clarify:

My table looks like this:

```
GRIDCODE     BSMPW
1            empty (that does not stand in there, its just blanc)
1            empty
3            empty
1            empty
4            empty
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
GRIDCODE     BSMPW
1            BSM
1            BSM
3            BSE
1            BSM
4            BSP
```

I did this with another table before and it worked just fine. The BSMPW column is set as TEXT while the GRIDCODE is set as integer.

Comment: Did you mean `BSMPW == "1"` instead of `GRIDCODE == "1"`. GRIDCODE is a class.

Comment: In addition to the above, also be sure the value you are comparing to (BSMPW) is of type string, if you pass an int then it will always fail and return "None". `1 != "1"`. How you end up calling this method would probably help clarify any problems that are occurring.

Comment: I defined GRIDCODE as a class because I got an errormessage: `Global name not defined`. I removed the `class GRIDCODE: pass` now and its working without the errormessage but still populates the fields with None. 
All of the values I am checking are numbers and I want to populates the fields with text...
I am working with ArcMap and trz to fill in values in an Attributetable. i am working here with the FieldCalculator.

Comment: If you're only passing numbers then that would be your problem. You're checking a number (type int) against a sentence (type string) so they will never equate to true. You got the global name error because you are using GRIDCODE in your if statements instead of BSMPW as @AamirAdnan said.

Comment: I want to populate empty cells in BSMPW (column) with BSP, BSE, BSM depending on the value in the cells of the GRIDCODE (column). I only want to check, and if there is a `1`, I want to write `BSP` into an empty cell, which is setted as `TEXT` by arcmap. Doing this is shouldnt matter if I am checking numbers or letters cause I dont want to replace something and since I want to write in `BSMPW` it needs to be there? Or am I totally wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that Bob and Aamir are pointing out is that GRIDCODE has no value, and thus can't equal anything, rendering the rest of your change() function moot. If you want to use a certain value of GRIDCODE, your code might look like this.

```
class GRIDCODE:
  def __init__(self, BSMPW):
    self.BSMPW = BSMPW

  def getBSMPW(self):
    return self.BSMPW

def change(BSMPW):
  if BSMPW == "1":
    return "BSM"
  elif BSMPW == "3":
    return "BSE"
  elif BSMPW == "4":
    return "BSP"
  else:
    return "None"

newGrid = GRIDCODE("1")
print change(newGrid.getBSMPW())
#prints "BSM"
```

However, the easiest way to do this, if I correctly understand what you're saying, is to skip the class entirely and use the CSV module, as long as the columns can be converted into a CSV. Then you could go line by line, and run the change function for each row.

Comment: Wrong person, haha. However, reading your updates, it looks like you just want to remove the quotes around your integers, although I may be completely off.

Comment: Yep. Wrong person. But that was (one) of the problem(s). I got rid of them and it worked. I also changed `change(BSMPW)` to `change(GRIDCODE)`

Comment: That definitely works too! It's the exact same solution since the variable name there is arbitrary. Just make sure to remember that, so you don't get confused. It might even be worth changing the name to something like gc_bsmpw or something similar, so it's obvious that you're not referencing the GRIDCODE class there. Regardless though, happy to help, and thanks for giving me my first bit of reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I figured I would further elaborate with an answer and why you might be receiving your error. As discussed, you shouldn't need the class as where it is right now is not being used. What you want would be the following:

```
def change(BSMPW):
    if BSMPW == "1":
        return "BSM"
    elif BSMPW == "3":
        return "BSE"
    elif BSMPW == "4":
        return "BSP"
    else:
        return "None"
```

Noticed how we are now switching on BSMPW, instead of GRIDCODE. You were switching on a non-existance variable (which is probably why it threw global errors before). Since it never equated to any of your given situations it always returned none. However, there is still a problem in your code which I want to express here as well.

If you are passing it an int it will ALWAYS give you none. This is because you are trying to compare an integer with a string. The following example elaborates on it a little bit:

```
change(1)
>> None
change("1")
>> BSM
```

If you are passing it an integer then you need to compare it to integers. So you would need to change your code to this:

```
def change(BSMPW):
    if BSMPW == 1:
        return "BSM"
    elif BSMPW == 3:
        return "BSE"
    elif BSMPW == 4:
        return "BSP"
    else:
        return "None"
```

However if you wish to be "pythonic" and implement an efficient switch statement you would want to do the following (again if you are comparing to strings add quotes):

```
def change(BSMPW):
    switch = {1 : "BSM",
              3 : "BSE",
              4 : "BSP"}
    return switch.get(BSMPW, "None")
```

Comment: Hello Bob. Thanks for your effort. I edited my questions to clarify it